# Using Xcode instruments and making changes

Tags: xcode, instruments, xcode-instruments

Say I discover a retain cycle using Instruments and I fix it in code. Do I really have to

1. return to xcode
2. build and run the app in the simulator
3. terminate the process / quit simulator / stop in xcode
4. and hit profile within xcode

??

Is this how everyone else uses instruments when making changes?

Comment: How do you expect Instruments to know about your code fix without you rebuilding the project and profiling it again? How do you even know your code fix fixes the problem without building the project and profiling it in Instruments?

Comment: Are you trying to misunderstand me? :-D Ofcourse I want to apply changes and verify that the fix is solving the issue. So, yes, I want to rebuild, but does it really have to be as tedious as I describe in the list?

Comment: What is it you find tedious: having to run the app in the simulator and stopping it, or something else? If you build for the simulator you can reduce Step 2 to "build", and you can eliminate Step 3. Choosing Product > Build for Profiling will build your project for Instruments without running it.

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing. When making a change to the code and hitting Cmd-I, Instruments does not seem to get the latest code. So I resorted to first doing Cmd-R to build and run in simulator, then quit. Then Cmd-I to launch in Instruments again and hit Record. This seemed to work. For a while. But recently I've found that I have to completely shut down Instruments between each profiling run, and then hit Cmd-I again, and choose the template again to actually get it to use the latest code.

Comment: God forbid they could include a menu command to 'Build AND Profile.' That would just take up too much menu space...